# Arduino Pro Mini stopped working / broken

Tags: battery

I need help, currently I am working in final project about portable monitoring system. I am using Arduino Pro Mini 5V/16MHz as microcontroller and a Li-Po battery to power it up through XL6019 boost converter. I have created the PCB and assembly all components but suddenly when I turned it on, the Arduino Pro Mini suddenly stopped working. Recently I am adding a feature to measure the battery capacity so I connected the battery voltage to arduino pro mini Analog Pin, is that the problem? But I have tested the method of measuring battery capacity using Arduino Uno before and it worked fine. [image: This is the schematic of the system I am used to create the PCB].
I am confused right now about what is the main problem.. and also is there any way to repair the Pro Mini? The Pro Mini used in project can't be reseted and I can't upload any program to it.
Pls help.

Comment: What voltage did you connect to the Pro Mini's analog pin? Was it greater than 5 VDC?

Comment: The Li-Po battery output voltage, it around 3V - 4.2V (fully charged).

Comment: Are you have checked the voltage in the output of XL6019 is 5V?